# "borrowed value does not live long enough" when using a struct with a slice

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, rust-obsolete

> Editor's note: The code in this question predates Rust 1.0. Since then, semantics have changed and some of the assertions made in the question are no longer true.

I have the following piece of code:

```
extern crate debug;

use std::mem::size_of_val;

struct A<'a> {
    a: &'a [i64],
}

fn main() {
    // code
}
```

When I define a slice with `&` (i.e. `&[1, 2, 3]`) as in the following `println!`

```
println!("{} - {:?}", size_of_val(&A { a: &[1, 2, 3] }), A { a: &[1, 2, 3] });
```

the output is

> ```
> 16 - A<'static>{a: &[1i64, 2i64, 3i64]}
> ```

Defining a slice without `&`

```
println!("{} - {:?}", size_of_val(&A { a: [1, 2, 3] }), A { a: [1, 2, 3] });
```

gives me the same result

> ```
> 16 - A<'static>{a: &[1i64, 2i64, 3i64]}
> ```

If I first try to bind an instance of a struct `A`, whose `a` field is initialized with a reference to a slice (i.e. using `&`), to a variable `x`

```
let x = A { a: &[1, 2, 3] }; // &[1, 2, 3] is a reference to a slice
```

and I try to execute a similar `println!` as the previous ones

```
println!("{} - {:?}", size_of_val(&x), x);
```

I get

> ```
> 16 - A<'static>{a: &[1i64, 2i64, 3i64]}
> ```

However, if I bind an instance of `A`, whose `a` field is initialized to a slice (not a reference to a slice using `&`), to a variable `x`

```
let x = A { a: [1, 2, 3] };
```

and I try to execute a similar `println!` as the previous ones

```
println!("{} - {:?}", size_of_val(&x), x);
```

I get the following build error:

> ```
> /prpath/main.rs:12:20: 12:29 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
> /prpath/main.rs:12     let x = A { a: [1 ,2, 3] };
>                                         ^~~~~~~~~
> /prpath/main.rs:11:11: 15:2 note: reference must be valid for the block at 11:10...
> /prpath/main.rs:11 fn main() {
> /prpath/main.rs:12     let x = A { a: [1 ,2, 3] };
> /prpath/main.rs:13 
> /prpath/main.rs:14     println!("{} - `{:?}`", size_of_val(&x), x);
> /prpath/main.rs:15 }
> /prpath/main.rs:12:5: 12:31 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 12:4; consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
> /prpath/main.rs:12     let x = A { a: [1 ,2, 3] };
>                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> error: aborting due to previous error
> ```

I was expecting that only the `A { a: &[1, 2, 3] }` definition was allowed because `A.a` should have `&[i64]` type, but, apparently, Rust allows us to not include an `&` symbol.

What is the difference between `A { a: &[1, 2, 3] }` and `A { a: [1, 2, 3] }`? Why are we allowed to use `A { a: [1, 2, 3] }` (in the second example above)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can use a `[T,..n]` where a `&[T]` is expected, the conversion to a slice is implicit. So following code is perfectly valid:

```
let a = [1u, 2, 3];
let b: &[uint] = a;
```

Your situation is a purely lifetime problem. Your struct is

```
struct A<'a> {
    a: &'a [i64],
}
```

It holds a **slice**. A slice is nothing more than a reference to the first element and a count of the number of elements. That's why `size_of_val()` called on a `A` will always return 16: it's the size of a slice, one u64 for the pointer, and one u64 for the number of elements (as you seems to be on a 64bits computer).

So in your code, **the struct does not own the array**. The difference in behavior you observe is due to the difference about when the array does out of scope.

**First case:**

```
let x = A { a: [1, 2, 3] };
```

Here you define an array, and stores a slice to this array in your struct. Then when reaching the `;`, your array does out of scope and is destroyed, and thus the reference in `x` is not valid anymore: it is forbidden by the compiler.

**Second case:**

```
let x = A { a: &[1, 2, 3] };
```

It is more peculiar. Your array is stored in an anonymous variable. In fact, writing

```
let foo = &42u;
```

is equivalent to writing

```
let _anonymousvariable = 42u;
let foo = &_anonymousvariable;
```

Except that you can't reach `_anonymousvariable` directly.

It's exactly the same for you, your code is equivalent to

```
let _anonymous_array = [1, 2, 3]
let x = A { a: &_anonymous_array };
```

and thus is perfectly valid.

**Last case:**

When you write everything directly in the `println!()`. Thanks to previous case, we now see why this works:

```
println!("{} - {:?}", size_of_val(&A { a: &[1, 2, 3] }), A { a: &[1, 2, 3] });
```

but in this case there is no problem either:

```
println!("{} - {:?}", size_of_val(&A { a: [1, 2, 3] }), A { a: [1, 2, 3] });
```

because your arrays only go out of scope when reaching the `;`, and no reference to them exist past this point, so they can be safely deleted and the compiler is happy.